# Calculating Word Frequency in a String Without Using "Import" or NLTK

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I write a text and I try to calculate word frequency for every word without using "import" and NLTK. It will be like this:

input:
example = " I will go to cinema tomorrow."

output:

| word | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| I | 1 |
| will | 1 |
| go | 1 |

Comment: You can use builtins without import. Like a dict.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Use OP example
example = " I will go to cinema tomorrow."

# replace can be used to remove the components you might not want to count.
# Following the OP example, . was not to be counted in the output.
tkns = example.replace(".", "").split()

# Using dict comprehension, one can iterate over the tokens and use count to count the occurrences.
# Since dict doesn't allow multiple keys, if a token shows up multiple times, in the output it will show up only once as a key in the dict and it will have the proper amount of occurrences associated.
{t :tkns.count(t) for t in tkns}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may have to do some "cleaning" to your sting first (e.g. remove periods, colons, etc.). But then what you can do is:

```py
s = "I will go to cinema tomorrow"

# split into words
words = s.split(" ")

# count words
result = Counter(words)

# Huzza!
print(result)
```

Comment: you can't just call `Counter` without importing it